# I have to convert ros message to opencv image

Tags: python, opencv, ros

I tried to subscribe to a topic called /image and tried to convert the ros message to a opencv image. Here below is the code.

```
rospy.Subscriber("image", SenMsg.Image)

rospy.spin()

cv_image = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(Image, "bgr8") 

cv2.imwrite('img.jpg',cv_image)
```

But when i do that, i am not able to write any thing.. there is no output at all.. can any one help me ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look here: http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/ConvertingBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImagesPython

Comment: @AlexToind maybe you should post your comment as an answer inc. few more words so this question can be closed.